# Scalable Regexmatch formular

Tags: google-sheets

i need help with the following formula:

IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B3), JOIN("|",Keywords!H$2:H$13)),"unqualified","qualified")

B3 is in this Case the String "I need help". My problem is that id like to use the Formula

IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B3), JOIN("|",Keywords!H$2:H)),"unqualified","qualified")

so i dont always need to match the Row with the Keywords. Otherwise i have Spaces in the join formular and the results are always "unqualified".

Does anyone has an idea how i can rewrite this formula into a more "scalable Version"?

I hope everything i explained was understandable.

Comment: Can you share a sample or copy of your spreadsheet so we are able to try working around it and provide you with a tested working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Remove sensitive data if any.

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). You may also try the [Blank sheet maker here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with this formula:

```
IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B3), JOIN("|",QUERY(G$2:G,"select G Where G is not null"))),"unqualified","qualified")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out. You can remove the LOWER and make the regex case insensitive

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK(B3:B),,
   IF(
    REGEXMATCH(
     B3:B, 
     "(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,Keywords!H2:H13)),
    "unqualified",
    "qualified")))
```